# What will be battery life of iPhone, if I use CLLocationManger with kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers?

Tags: iphone, ios, gps

If I am using CLLocationManger with kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers for getting Coordinates and never stop it. 
Have you any idea that in how much time my iPhone battery will drain?

Comment: Similar question & answer is here, take a look at.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377467/what-is-active-gps-effect-on-mobile-devices-battery-life?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is difficult to answer as there are many variables involved, such as, device model, device age, OS version, GPS chipset (varies among device models), ... This is one of the reasons why you should strive to optimize your usage of the GPS functionality.

Apple, for example, caches location data on regular time intervals so it can provide third party applications with location data (1) fast and (2) without the need to fire up the onboard GPS, which requires time and power. (For your information, cached location data is of course not an option if your application relies heavily on location services).

In short, don't count the battery for your application to function properly. Instead, make clever use of the location services.

Comment: Thank you for reply. my device is iPhone4.

Comment: Please tell me how to use location services in iPhone ( not GPS)?.

Comment: Location services is a general term for interacting with the CoreLocation framework. It is also important to note that it is not possible to directly interact with the device's GPS. The operating system will determine what capabilities it will use, based on availability, for example. The device will not only use GPS for determining the device's location. Cell tower triangulation is another option. The bottom line is that you will need to use the Core Location framework and optimize your use of it as much as possible to use the device's limited power as efficiently as possible.

Comment: please tell me one more thing that if I use kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers instead of kCLLocationAccuracyBest.
Then will my iPhone use GPS or Cell tower.

Comment: I don't think that this is specified in the documentation. In fact, I don't think that the degree of accuracy is strictly tied to any particular protocol. The device will make use of what is available at any time and this depends on the circumstances.