# Taxonomy of battery life in smartphone devices

Tags: android, iphone

I am trying to write an application on android and iPhone , my app will use three types of techniques (or maybe more)
GPS , WIFI and Bluetooth , but I am trying to have a deep look on the taxonomy of the battery life on these factors?
Is there any formal study in general that shows a comparison between these factors i.e. I guess they consume battery life in my app
I want my app to be power efficient .
So as I can find a way to reduce the power consummation , or at least use other techniques if available.

Answer (score 0):

It's virtually impossible to accurately get a measurement, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3377522/3436942 - there's just too many factors - as for a way to reduce consumption - how about turning these off when not in use (create permissions the user agrees to)?

Comment: thanks i agree with you , but shouldn’t be a study or manual in for example Apple for IPhone saying that WIFI could consume xxx battery life per xxx for a special device or at least for an end user to know

Comment: no, as again, signal strength/IOS/age/etc will all have an impact. By saying nothing, they're protecting themselves by saying *yes, it will use more battery*, but not even they know exactly *how much* will be used. It's like asking someone what temperature it is? they can look at a thermometer, but not even that can be 100% accurate (due to wind speed/etc).